# Third party map in ApostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am a beginner in the apostrophe. I want to add a third-party map like leaflet map in my apostrophe project.

I have added a leaflet map in home.html and it works fine, but how to integrate with apostrophe places?

Answer (score 0):

Is the intention to create a custom widget, that displays a Leaflet map using data from `apostrophe-places`, or a piece extending `apostrophe-places`?

If so, I would recommend subclassing `apostrophe-pieces-widgets`, and use the data given to you via `data.widget` in the widget view (`views/widget.html`).

Additionally, you can provide custom front-end js to wire up Leaflet via custom [widget player](https://docs.apostrophecms.org/apostrophe/tutorials/getting-started/custom-widgets#adding-a-javascript-widget-player-on-the-browser-side).

I've never used Leaflet before, but their documentation seems straight forward (https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/)

Comment: Yes @grdunn, I want to create a custom widget that displays a Leaflet map using data from apostrophe-places.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan do you have a more specific question related to this?